# Escape php eol from string PHP

Tags: php, sql, string, escaping

I want escape string `PHP_EOL` or double quote `"\n"` selected from db

I tried:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    $str = 'Hello\nWorld!';
    echo $str;
    sqlInsert("insert ... (str) values ('{$str}')");
```

**Output** worked

```
Hello\nWorld!
```

But when I want get it from database:

```
$str2  = sqlget("select ... str");
echo ''.$str2;
```

**Will be:** not working

```
Hello
World!
```

What's Problem!

Comment: Using echo nl2br($str2);

Comment: Use double quotes $str = "Hello\nWorld!";

Comment: I want to escape new line!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL doesn't works as PHP with EOL in single or double quoted strings.

You could either / or :

**1. Store backslash in your database :**

You need to escape the backslashes :

```
$str = 'Hello\nWorld!';
echo $str ;
$str = str_replace('\\n','\\\\n',$str);
sqlInsert("insert ... (str) values ('{$str}')");
```

**2. Transform the output :**

Replace newlines by litteral `\n` :

```
$str = get_from_sql(...);
$str = str_replace("\n", '\n', $str);
```